# AS3 Touch Event to make Object/Character move upwards, having difficulty with code

Tags: android, actionscript, touch

I'm building my first game application for Android on Flash CS6 Actionscript 3.0. 
What I'm trying to achieve is either:

Touch and hold press (character moves upward) Release finger (character falls towards the ground)

OR:

Tap (character moves up a few pixels) and Release (character falls down a few pixels).

I've looked all over the place and I've managed to put this together:

```
elephantp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, isPressed);

private function isPressed(event:TouchEvent):void
{
    var touch:touch = event.getTouch(elephantp);

    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.BEGAN)
    {
        trace("pressed just now");

        elephantp.y += 5;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onButtonHold);
    }

    if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.ENDED)
    {
        trace("release");

        elephantp.y -= 5;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onButtonHold);
    }
}
```

//OR

```
private function onButtonHold(e:Event):void
{
    trace("doing stuff while button pressed!");
}


 Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

 elephantp.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, fl_TapHandler);

 function fl_TapHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
    {

        elephantp.y += 5;

    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Sorry hunter! Just realised I never did ask a question. Thank you for your interest but I've managed to tweak a different code to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

You have try to use `TouchEvent.BEGIN` and `TouchEvent.END` instead `TouchEvent.TOUCH` ?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary

...maybe like the "TouchEventExample.as"

Also, using constants for the amount of you movement will make future amount change easier.